# Can't run iPhone 5s simulator in new XCode6.1

Tags: ios7, iphone-5, xcode6.1

I just upgraded my macbook OS to Yosemite and updated XCode from 6.0 to 6.1 and now when I build my project and try to run for iPhone 5s with iOS7.0 simulator , it gives me an error saying "**iPhone 5s is not available, please select a different device and try again**". In XCode 6.0, this was working totally fine.

Following are the build settings for my app

```
   Architecture - Standard Architecture(armv7, arm64)
   Base SDK - Latest iOS(iOS 8.1)
   Valid architectures - arm64, armv7, armv7s
   iOS Deployment Target - iOS6
```

Comment: You can go to Xcode (on menu bar) -> Preferences... -> Downloads -> click install iPhone Simulator iOS 7 and iOS 7.1. I have the same issue and this worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the real answer

```
The earliest simulator runtime supported on Yosemite is 7.1.
```

Answer (score 2):

Also happened here with iPhone 5s 7.1 being used. I found out I had accidentally interrupted the 7.1 simulator download. I had to open Downloads ( Command + , ) and let Xcode finish downloading it.